# How to Stream video from iPad to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, video, streaming, ipad

Could you advise how to stream video from iPad to Ubuntu 13.04 ?
I've tried the teamviewer, but it doesn't support from ipad -> ubuntu.

Appreciate any ideas,
Vladimir Zateychuk
skype: vzateychuk

Answer (score 0):

You can try XBMC, which can be easily configured (settings > network) to receive airplay content (audio & video). With my machine it did not run smoothely though.